# Replacing array value with a matching object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, javascript-objects

I'm building a react app to display esports matches from the pandascore api. I've pulled the dates of all of the matches and created a multi-layer array that groups them in to weeks.

I'm trying to replace the dates in the array that I've made with the corresponding match. This way, I can have an object with matches grouped by week.

```js
// map an array of dates
//getting dates that we will replace
// ie ["2018-07-29T20:41:28Z", "2018-07-29T21:32:14Z", "2018-08-05T01:08:11Z"]
Object.values(groups).map((matchDateTime) => {
  
  console.log(matchDateTime);

  //loop over every date in the array
  for (let d = 0; d < matchDateTime.length; d++) {

    //set a variable and set it to find a match from the matches array
    //that has the same date and time to the
    //entry in the matchDateTime array
    let matchWithDate = matches.reduce( match => {

      //if dates match, then we will replace the date in the 
      //matchDateTime array to the match object we found

      //this is the logic I'm looking for but doesn't return anything
      match.begin_at = matchDateTime[d] ? matchDateTime[d] = match : 'no match';

      //returns the correct date - line 71 in the screenshot
      console.log(matchDateTime[d]);
      //returns the correct match - line 72
        console.log(match);
        // returns the coresponding match date/time - line 73
       console.log(match.begin_at);

    }
    );

  }
  
 // console.log(groups);
});
```

What I'm getting is an error after the loop runs a few times. There shouldn't be any dates/times that are null or undefined as I've pulled them directly from the objects I'm checking against.

I feel like I'm close. Any help is appreciated!

[image]

Comment: You should probably re-review [array::reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). Its callback's first argument is *some* "accumulating" value (*which you also never return in the callback*) you are reducing an array into, the second argument is the current element of the array being iterated over. Your `array::map` use is questionable as well.

Comment: use `forEach` instead of `reduce`

Answer (score 0):

I altered my loop to use the `filter` method instead of `reduce`. I also edited my ternary operation to regular `if` logic.

Comment: Yes. It's giving the correct results, though I'm sure I can refactor this and be more efficient.